# Laravel - How can i get client's orders grouped by their status

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a situation which I can't fix, I have 3 tables / models with structure as below :

- Client Model : `Client->hasMany(Order::Class)`
- Order Model : `Order->belongsTo(Client::Class)` and `Order->belongsTo(Status::Class)`
- Status Model : `Status->hasMany(Order::class)`

I want to be able to get each client's orders grouped by their statuses,  e.g : 3 cancelled - 4 completed - 5 processing

I tried this but didn't work :(

```
Client Model {


    public function {

        return $this->orders()->selectRaw('status_id, count(id) as total')->groupBy('status_id);

        // orders() = is the relation a client hasmany orders
    }

}
```

can anyone help please thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: it means that it didn't work as i expected i still have to find a client and chain on this method to get his orders groupedby status, i know i am still missing something also there is a limitation because not all client have orders yet so i need to implement some sort of $clients = Client::has('orders') and this return an empty array of item

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: i have the details models below :

class Client extends Model
{
public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class); 
    }
}

class Order extends Model
{
public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }
}

class Status extends Model
{
public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}

Comment: i have the details models below :

class Client extends Model
{
public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class); 
    }
}

class Order extends Model
{
public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }
}

class Status extends Model
{
public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}

e.g i want to have a list on view like : Orders : 3 Completed - 2 Processing - 2 Cancelled

Comment: How are you using the query/relationship you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Define this way your relationship in the Client model

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}

public function getOrdersCompletedAttribute()
{
    return $this->orders->where('id_status', 5)->count();
}

public function getOrdersProcessingAttribute()
{
    return $this->orders->where('id_status', 1)->count();
}
```

Supposing status 1 = 'processing' and 5 = 'completed'

You can access de attribute like this:

```
$client->orders_completed
```

To get 4